# canvas.toDataURL creates blank image in Chrome

Tags: canvas

I'm using this [function][1] to get a frame from an uploaded video.
It properly works on FF (v.113) while in Google Chrome (v.113) data:image/png;base64 is empty
All the workaround, get from the comments and the answers, to fix the Chrome behavior didn't work. Any idea how to approach to a solution?

```
getFrame = () => {

    var input = document.getElementById('upload');
    var img = document.getElementById('thumbnail');    

    input.addEventListener('change', function (event) {

      var file = event.target.files[0];
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      video.src = url;

      var snapshot = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 150);
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        video.removeEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
      };
      video.addEventListener('canplay', snapshot);
    });
```

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTZtC.png)

[1]: rodrigo-silveira | [PHP - Extract frame during Video upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261448/php-extract-frame-during-video-upload/36046775#36046775)